# SVN post commit: Who is the user that committed?

Tags: svn, svn-hooks, post-commit-hook

In an SVN post commit hook, how can I get the user who executed the commit?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Using the `svnlook` command with [`author`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnlook.c.author.html). For example, in a shell script, it might be:

```
REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"

AUTHOR="$(svnlook author -r $REV $REPOS)"
```

Answer (score 6):

`post-commit` hook script example:

```
#!/bin/sh
REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"
AUTHOR="$(svnlook author $REPOS -r $REV)"

# output on STDERR will be marshalled back to SVN client
echo "This transaction was commited by '$AUTHOR'!" 1>&2

exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter to your post-commit script will be the revision number - you can use this to query SVN for whatever information you need.